# Mi 9 (M1902F1G) running MIUI 10.2.15.0 issue with fitness trackers

Tags: gps, xiaomi, gps-tracking, miui-10

I'm seeing issues with my new phone that it's not keeping the GPS enabled when fitness trackers are running.

E.g. a bike ride consists of a straight line between the start and end location.

I've tried [Ghostracer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bravetheskies.ghostracer) and [Strava](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava) and both seems to be having the same issues.

I've tried switching the "Battery Saver" setting for both apps to "No restrictions" (they were both previously on "Battery saver (recommended)"), but that makes no difference.

Anyone else with the same issue or ideally a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Use Adaptive Battery settings screenshot]([![https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksOeg.png]

Problem seems to be with the "Use Adaptive Battery" feature.

I'd guess it's not clever enough to differentiate between an app not being used very often, and an app being used after being recently installed.